# How/Can I set up an instance to use an already made for AWS ec2 using python 3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there a way of using a made key pair when creating a new instance using python 3. Can i just insert a new line into this code?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instance = ec2.create_instances(
    ImageId='ami-0713f98de93617bb4',
    MinCount=1,
    MaxCount=1,
    InstanceType='t2.nano')
print (instance[0].id)
```

Comment: you can use the EC2 boto3 client to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks! Say when i run that code above, it creates a new instance, but what key does it use? When i check my AWS console it has nothing under key pair.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a KeyName parameter like this:

```
instance = ec2.create_instances(
    ImageId='ami-0713f98de93617bb4',
    MinCount=1,
    MaxCount=1,
    InstanceType='t2.nano',
    KeyName='myKeyName')
```

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.create_instances

Comment: Thanks, i had tried this earlier but i still couldn't login into the server. But i assume that's because i haven't set up ssh right?

Comment: You have to make sure you're issuing the SSH command with the private key name like this:  ssh -i myKeyName.pem ec2-user@ip-addr